# Connecting User Ethereum account with Metamask in ReactJS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, I am pretty new to programming, so please bear with me =)

I am building an app, which requires users to connect their Metamask accounts.
I would like to be able to store web3 related functions in a separate js file. I am currently working on a reusable Metamask Connect Button. Here is what the code of the button looks like:

```
export default function MetamaskBtn() {
  function connect() {
    window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
  }
  console.log(connect);
  return (
    <button
      onClick={connect}
      style={{
        id: 'metamaskbtn',
        gridArea: 'web3',
        fontSize: '60%',
        border: 'solid 1px #174666',
        background: '#E36E1A',
        borderRadius: '3px',
        placeSelf: 'center'
      }}>
      Connect Wallet
    </button>
  )
}
```

which works fine, now I am trying to save that `connect()` function in an external js file, which i called `ConnectMetamask`:

```
export function ConnectMetamask() {
  window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestedAccounts' })
}
```

Then I tried importing the file into my jsx file with no success :

```
import { ConnectMetamask } from "../../../../_JS Functions/web3Function";

const Metamask = ConnectMetamask

export default function MetamaskBtn() {
  console.log(Metamask);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={Metamask}
      style={{
        id: 'metamaskbtn',
        gridArea: 'web3',
        fontSize: '60%',
        border: 'solid 1px #174666',
        background: '#E36E1A',
        borderRadius: '3px',
        placeSelf: 'center'
      }}>
      Connect Wallet
    </button>
  )
}
```

I `console.log()` both functions and they print the same thing in fact.
`connect()`:

```
ƒ connect() {
    window.ethereum.request({
      method: 'eth_requestAccounts'
    });
  }
```

`ConnectMetamask()`

```
ƒ ConnectMetamask() {
  window.ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_requestedAccounts'
  });
}
```

The error I get from the latter is:

```
index.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: The method 'eth_requestedAccounts' does not exist / is not available. {code: -32601, message: "The method 'eth_requestedAccounts' does not exist / is not available.", data: {…}}
```

and

```
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) {code: -32601, message: "The method 'eth_requestedAccounts' does not exist / is not available.", data: {…}}
```

Hope someone can help me out with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in fact I just realized it was a problem of typo =) hehe-..
should be `'eth_requestAccounts'` not `'eth_requestedAccounts'`

Answer (score -1):

You could use a package if you are using React. (I created one)
[react-dapp-web3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dapp-web3)
I'm still working on it but maybe helps you :D

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.